# Why does the '<' not transform into a '>' when it reaches a '*'?

Tags: c

This is part of a larger program that is a game where the user must navigate a map. In this function, the '<' and '>' characters are meant to move in the direction that they point. Should they reach the border of the map, represented by an asterisk, they should change into the opposite sign. The problem I have is that the '<' character just disappears when it reaches an asterisk. In opposition, the '>' behaves exactly how it should; when it is one space behind an asterisk, it reverses, and begins moving in the opposite direction. I genuinely do not know why the '<' does not do the same, as it is virtually the same code, but in reverse. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
void moveCar(int rows, int cols, char **map) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i < rows; i+=2) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (map[i][j] == '>') {
                if (j < cols - 1) {
                    if (map[i][j + 1] == '.') {
                        map[i][j + 1] = '>';
                        map[i][j] = '.';
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (map[i][j + 1] == '*') {
                        map[i][j] = '<';
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (map[i][j] == '<') {
                if (j > 0) {
                    if (map[i][j - 1] == '.') {
                        map[i][j - 1] = '<';
                        map[i][j] = '.'; 
                    }
                    else if (map[i][j - 1] == '*') { 
                        map[i][j] = '>';
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                map[i][j] = '.';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the `*` with `.` long before the `<` hits it. I guess your full program repairs the `*`, and by doing so overwrites the `<` in the very first column. Therefore, you need extra code to keep the `*` (maybe starting `j` from 1 might be sufficient):

```
void moveCar(int rows, int cols, char **map) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i < rows; i+=2) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (map[i][j] == '>') {
                if (j < cols - 1) {
                    if (map[i][j + 1] == '.') {
                        map[i][j + 1] = '>';
                        map[i][j] = '.';
                        j++;
                    }
                    else if (map[i][j + 1] == '*') {
                        map[i][j] = '<';
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (map[i][j] == '<') {
                if (j > 0) {
                    if (map[i][j - 1] == '.') {
                        map[i][j - 1] = '<';
                        map[i][j] = '.';
                    }
                    else if (map[i][j - 1] == '*') {
                        map[i][j] = '>';
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (map[i][j] != '*') {
                map[i][j] = '.';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @efx in this case, please accept the answer ;)

Comment: ah my bad sorry, done it now :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the ‘<’ character disappearing when it reaches an asterisk might be due to the break statement in the inner loop. When the ‘>’ character reaches an asterisk, the code changes it to ‘<’ and then breaks out of the inner loop. This means that the rest of the row is not processed, and any ‘<’ characters present in that row will not be updated.

On the other hand, when the ‘<’ character reaches an asterisk, it is changed to ‘>’, but the inner loop continues to run. This means that if there is another ‘<’ character present in that row, it will be processed and updated. If this ‘<’ character is also at an asterisk, it will be changed to ‘>’, overwriting the previous change.

To fix this issue, you can remove the break statement from the inner loop. This will ensure that all characters in a row are processed and updated correctly. Here’s the corrected code:

```
void moveCar(int rows, int cols, char **map) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i < rows; i+=2) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (map[i][j] == '>') {
                if (j < cols - 1) {
                    if (map[i][j + 1] == '.') {
                        map[i][j + 1] = '>';
                        map[i][j] = '.';
                    }
                    else if (map[i][j + 1] == '*') {
                        map[i][j] = '<';
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (map[i][j] == '<') {
                if (j > 0) {
                    if (map[i][j - 1] == '.') {
                        map[i][j - 1] = '<';
                        map[i][j] = '.'; 
                    }
                    else if (map[i][j - 1] == '*') { 
                        map[i][j] = '>';
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                map[i][j] = '.';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think this will help you brother...

Comment: thanks, but I had to put that break in there, because if not all the '>' characters immediately went to the right of the map and changed to a '<' instead of simply moving one space forward.

Comment: Instead of the break, just do a `j++` to skip the recently moved '>'.

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller thanks, the '>' work fine now. However, the '<' characters still disappear once they reach the asterisk